# Thumbnail Creation Cause 100%CPU

Tags: nautilus, video, thumbnails

Opening folder with .jpg images or .mp4 or .mkv etc. causes 100% cpu utilization.  Ubuntu 14.04, Lenovo T540P.  I do not want thumbnails written constantly on my SSD. Using dconf editor I selected "disable all" which solves the problem  for all videos but not .jpg folders.  There must be a way to prevent this.  Adding individual app entries will work for the videos but will not stop thumbnails of .jpg folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use dconf editor and set thumbnails to "disable all".  Set file preferences to generate thumbnails "never".  Clear .cache/thumbnails then redirect all output to .cache/thumbnails to dev/null.  Done, no thumbnails, no more 100% cpu utilization opening any folder with any content.  Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: Would you be so kind and share with us, what **exactly** you did to "redirect all output of .cache/thumbnails to /dev/null"? with kind regards